# Asp.Net Core routing parameters always 0 or null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-2.0

I've got what I take to be a very standard controller:

Here's the controller definition (a bit of dependency injection, but standard):

```
public class SeriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment  _env;

    public SeriesController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    [HttpGet("/series/{id:int?}/{title?}")]
    public IActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var populateSeriesItem = new PopulateSeriesItem(_env, new SqlConnection());

            var seriesItem = populateSeriesItem.GenerateSeriesItem(id);

    //...
```

If the id is absent (or 0), then it displays all records; if it's 1 or greater, it displays a single record. (This is how the client wants it!)

I call it as follows:

https://localhost/series/3/title

or

https://localhost/series/4/

but the problem is id is always 0 (and title null).

That's the case if I type it into the URL bar or specify id manually (i.e., /series?id=3)

I just can't figure out what I'm missing.

The exact same setup works perfectly with a different controller.

```
    [HttpGet("/books/{id:int?}/{title?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var populateBookItem = new PopulateBookItem(new  SqlConnection(), _env);

            var bookItem = populateBookItem.GenerateBookItem(id);
```

That one works.

This is the routing configuration (just standard):

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

I must be missing something obvious, but I'm baffled!

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Update:

I've stripped away all the functionality from the controller. I'm just literally passing it to a view.

This works: https://localhost:44319/series/14/megacities - the view reports id = 14.

This works: https://localhost:44319/series/5/megacities - the view reports id = 5

This works: https://localhost:44319/series/14/business-with-china - the view reports id = 14.

This doesn't work: https://localhost:44319/series/5/business-with-china - it goes to https://localhost:44319/series/0.

There are other URLs that follow the same pattern. Some working, some not working.

If I strip out the title parameter, they all seem to work.

I've no idea why!

Comment: Can you share routing configuration?

Comment: I've added it above! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting [FromRoute] in front of your parameters?

Comment: Thanks. [FromRoute} didn't make any difference. :(

Comment: Sorry, which leading slash? - So it reads series/{id;int?}/{title?}

Answer (score 5):

1. Remove  `routes.MapRoute`, it isn't necessary for Web API.
2. HTTPGet should look like `[HttpGet("/books/{id:int?}")]`
3. Add query parameters to request GET `api/books/5?title=abc`
4. Method definition:

```js
 [HttpGet("/books/{id:int?}")]
 public ActionResult Index(int id, [FromQuery] string title)
 {
    //code here
 }
```

Comment: It's not a Web API. Standard MVC.

Comment: @user5956088 understood. we have two ways to specify route : MapRoute  or Attributes. You can left MapRoute  for usual situations and modify attribute as i said.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a mismatch in names, parameter will resolve as default value - 0 in case of numbers and null otherwise
In the example below, url has param1 whereas the method has parameter name as param2.

```
[HttpGet("/foo/{param1}")]
public ActionResult Foo(int param2)
{
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so I found this link. I accidentally found the solution for my problem so I even it is not related to your, I post it for anyone who comes here who may have the same problem as me.
I am using C# and .net Core 2.2
I was getting id value to be 0 no matter what I did. 
It happened that the parameter name I chose, which was "page", the page number, needed to be "id" the same name as the specified in {id?}

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everybody's help.

I've solved the problem, though I don't know what was causing it. (I think it might have been a browser caching issue.)

Anyway, I restarted the server, and everything now works as it should.